# 18.04 Completely disable on-screen keyboard

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, onscreen-keyboard

I'm running an app in kiosk mode. Currently swiping up triggers the Ubuntu on-screen keyboard.  How can I completely disable this keyboard? I will never want it in this instance

Comment: Confirmed, the Gnome extension fixed this for me https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/